# Forced to click twice to reopen menu after body click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've written the following code to close a dropdown menu when click is outside the menu itself.

Looks like this:

```
jQuery("body").click(function() {
  jQuery("ul.dropdown-menu").removeClass('expanded');
  jQuery("button.dropdown").removeClass('active');
  jQuery("button.dropdown").attr("aria-expanded","false");
});

jQuery("ul.dropdown-menu").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery("button.dropdown").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It works fine, but when I close the menu clicking somewhere on the body, I'll be forced to click twice to `button.dropdown` to open it again.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the code you use when opening with a click?

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap?